# NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, general-network-error

I'm using React for front-end and Nodejs with express for backend and I have this error when my app tries to make an API call, in the local environment it works perfectly but not in production.

[Api Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMHcX.png)

[NetworkError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlqCI.png)

***I have this in the console:***

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/badges. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

**fron-end code api.js**

```
const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000';

const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const randomNumber = (min = 0, max = 1) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
const simulateNetworkLatency = (min = 30, max = 1500) =>
  delay(randomNumber(min, max));

async function callApi(endpoint, options = {}) {
  await simulateNetworkLatency();

  options.headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json'
  };

  const url = BASE_URL + endpoint;
  const response = await fetch(url, options);
  const data = await response.json();

  return data;
}

const api = {
  badges: {
    list() {
      // throw new Error('500 server Error'); // esto ocurre cuando hay un error con la api
      // return []; // este seria el caso en donde llega la peticion vacia
      return callApi('/badges'); // esta es la llamada exitosa a la api, entregando todos los datos
    },
    create(badge) {
      // throw new Error('500: Server error');
      return callApi(`/badges`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(badge)
      });
    },
    read(badgeId) {
      return callApi(`/badges/${badgeId}`);
    },
    update(badgeId, updates) {
      return callApi(`/badges/${badgeId}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify(updates)
      });
    },
    // Lo hubiera llamado `delete`, pero `delete` es un keyword en JavaScript asi que no es buena idea :P
    remove(badgeId) {
      return callApi(`/badges/${badgeId}`, {
        method: 'DELETE'
      });
    }
  }
};

export default api;
```

**React Component Badges.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles/Badges.css';
import confLogo from '../images/badge-header.svg';
import BadgesList from '../components/BadgesList';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import api from '../api';
import PageLoading from '../components/PageLoading';
import PageError from '../components/PageError';
import MiniLoader from '../components/MiniLoader';

class Badges extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    error: null,
    data: undefined
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();

    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.fetchData, 5000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true, error: null });

    try {
      const data = await api.badges.list();
      this.setState({ loading: false, data: data }); // si todo sale bien se entrega la data en pantalla
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ loading: false, error: error }); // de esta forma se maneja el error
    }
  };



  render() {
    if (this.state.loading === true && !this.state.data) {
      return <PageLoading />;
    }

    if (this.state.error) {
      return <PageError error={this.state.error} />;
    } // si llegase a ocurrir un error este es el mensaje que se mostraria en pantalla
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="Badges">
          <div className="Badges__hero">
            <div className="Badges__container">
              <img
                className="Badges_conf-logo"
                src={confLogo}
                alt="Conf logo"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="Badges__container">
          <div className="Badges__buttons">
            <Link to="/badges/new" className="btn btn-primary">
              New badge
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className="Badge__list">
            <BadgesList badges={this.state.data} />

            {this.state.loading && <MiniLoader />}
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Badges;
```

**Server Side Seed.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const faker = require('faker');
const md5 = require('md5');

function createBadges(limit = 50) {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    const firstName = faker.name.firstName();
    const lastName = faker.name.lastName();
    const email = faker.internet.email();

    result.push({
      id: faker.random.uuid(),
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      jobTitle: faker.name.jobTitle(),
      twitter: `${firstName}${lastName}${faker.address.zipCode()}`,
      avatarUrl: `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/${md5(email)}?d=identicon`,
    });
  }

  return result;
}

function main() {
  const data = {
    badges: createBadges(),
  };

  fs.writeFileSync(
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'db.json'),
    JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)
  );
}

main();
```

[in this file db.json are all the api call data that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR534.png)

Comment: Please use npm package cors.https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors this will solve the issue

Comment: I'm trying it but it doesn't work yet. Could you be more specific, I found this probably causes:

Comment: Trying to access an https resource that has an invalid certificate will cause this error.// Trying to access an http resource from a page with an https origin will also cause this error. // As of Firefox 68, https pages are not permitted to access http://localhost, although this may be changed by Bug 1488740. //

Comment: The server did not respond to the actual request (even if it responded to the Preflight request). One scenario might be an HTTP service being developed that panicked without returning any data.